# Index out of bounds error

Tags: java, exception, gwt, arraylist

I am working on a program where i am recreating the saved widgets back on to the boundary panel. When i am creating them i am also trying to put the values into the ArrayList so that if i want to update and save the opened project i should be able to do so by getting the values from the ArrayList.

Here is how the code looks like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                if(ename.contains(result[i].getParticipateEntityName())){
                        ername.add(ename.indexOf(result[i].getParticipateEntityName()), result[i].getParticipateRelatioshipName());
                        etotalpartial.add(ename.indexOf(result[i].getParticipateEntityName()), result[i].getTotalPartial());
                }else if(wename.contains(result[i].getParticipateEntityName())){
                        wrname.add(wename.indexOf(result[i].getParticipateEntityName()), result[i].getParticipateRelatioshipName());
                }
}
```

Here ename, ername, etotalpartial, wename and wrname are all ArrayList. This piece of code is included in an asynchronous class method.

When i run the code i get error at "ername.add(ename......".

Here is the error stack:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:367)
    at com.e.r.d.client.ERD1$16.onSuccess(ERD1.java:898)
    at com.e.r.d.client.ERD1$16.onSuccess(ERD1.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:216)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:393)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannel.java:1713)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:165)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:264)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessages(BrowserChannel.java:1668)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:401)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:222)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Any input will be of great help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like ername or wrname is an empty array list. ername.size() will probably return 0 by the way...

You either want to use the add(Object object) method, or you can initialize a capacity by inserting the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++){
   ername.add(null);
}
```

and then your code should work...

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the [`public void add(int index, E element)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) method of `List` if you can not guarantee that the size of your list is greater than `index`.

That is what happening with your code. You have an empty list (`ername`), and `ename.indexOf(result[i].getParticipateEntityName())` is returning 1, thus the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. In other words, you have a list of size 0, and you are trying to insert an element at index 1.

Consider using the [`public boolean add(E e)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) method of `ArrayList` which appends the new element to the end of the list.

Comment: is there way around this because i want the ename value and the ername value to correspond with each other in terms of index?
Thank you.

Comment: You can use a `Map` instead, with the key being the `index`, and the value being `ename`.

Comment: Or you can use an array initialized to the needed capacity.

Comment: @Bluu: You'd be just wasting space.