# Adding items to empty List at specific locations in java

Tags: java

Is there any way I can make the below code work without commenting the 3rd line.

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(0,0);
    //list.add(1,null);
    list.add(2,2);
```

I want to add items to list at specific locations. But if I don't change the index to Nth position I am not being able to add at Nth as told in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534413/index-out-of-bounds-error/2534454#2534454).

I can't use a map because I don't want to miss a value when the keys are same. Also adding null values to a list for large lists will be an overhead. When there is a collision I want the item to take the next position(nearest to where it should have been).

Is there any **List implementation that shifts index before it tries to add the item**?

Comment: Why not use a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`?

Comment: Use a TreeMap since that allows iteration of the keys in order.

Comment: What's the desired behaviour when you have a collision at a key?

Comment: If you are worried about multiple elements with the same key you could use Guava's TreeMultimap.

Comment: You're not clear.  If you just want to append entries, just use plain old `add(value)`.  If you want entries at a specific location use `set(index, value)`.  If you want to insert entries use `add(index, value)`.  Perhaps if you explained what significance you attach to the index and the order of the elements it would make more sense.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I think you meant `Map<Integer, Integer>`? I think he meant the first param of the `add` method as the index of the element.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: I'm not sure. His mention of "can't use a map because I don't want to miss a vlaue when the keys are the same", suggested that he wanted multiple values for one key, but I could be wrong. As some have mentioned, the original post is not very clear about this and the original poster appears to be in no hurry to clarify this.

Comment: isn't that a case for an Array?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Oops, indeed. You're right. I didn't read that phrase.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels:That might be a good option but comes with an overhead of maintaining a List<Integers> instead of a single Integer at most locations. I dont know much about MultiMaps but will surly experiment on it now. I think array or Vector might be other potions.

Comment: What *significant* overhead do you mean? Have you profiled this and determined it to be a significant bottleneck in your program's speed?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels:Yes. It is a good option, but I did not want to change my data structure. As I needed to shift places in case of collision. I was thinking of coding or simplicity overhead rather than performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This still smells like you should be using a Map. Why not use a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`?

something like,

```
   private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();

   public void addItem(int key, int value) {
      List<Integer> list = myMap.get(key);
      if (list == null) {
         list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         myMap.put(key, list);
      }
      list.add(value);
   }

   public List<Integer> getItems(int key) {
      return myMap.get(key);
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use something like a [MultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html) if your only concern is not "missing a value" if the keys are the same.

I'm not sure how doing a shift/insert helps if I understand your problem statement--if the "key" is the index, inserting will lose the same information.

Comment: Specifically, a TreeMultimap provides in-order iteration of the keys.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Vector` and call [setSize](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#setSize%28int%29) to prepopulate with null elements.

However, your comment about the overhead of the nulls speaks to an associative container as the right solution.

Comment: I think we need setSize() method in List also.It can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Well, There are a couple of ways I would think to do this, if you are not adding items too frequently, then it might be a good idea to simply do a check to see if there is an item at that location before adding it.

```
if(list.get(X) == null)
{
 list.add(X,Y);
}
```

Otherwise if you are going to be doing this too often...then I would recommend creating your own custom List class, and extending ArrayList or whatever you are using, and simply override the add method, to deal with collisions.

Comment: Yes. I wanted the check to happen automatically and increase the size if it is less. Looks like I need to think about a custom list implementation to do it.

Comment: this simply does not work *at all*, since java.util.ArrayList#add(int, E) does do range check: `if (index > size || index < 0)` So for example you cannot add element at first index into empty list.